# Windows Curl Rest get Response and status to separate variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I am trying to call a REST GET service using curl in windows batch and trying to capture status code and response into different variables. I am able to capture the response to a variable. Could anyone suggest me how to capture both to separate variables? basically, I am trying to check rest response status and do appropriate action based on response code. if the response code is 200 I will read message body and do some operation on it.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 'curl -sw %{http_code} localhost:8080/someservice' ) do (
    set _CmdResult=%%a
    set _status = something
)
if (status is equal to 500 or 404 ) 
exit 
else echo _CmdResult
```

I am new to the batch script. sorry if the question doesn't make sense